# Receiving error php_mbstring.dll No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, php5, php

I am receiving this error in apache error log during httpd restart process.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll' -
> /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I already installed php_mbstring previously

> yum install php-mbstring
>
> Package php-mbstring-5.3.10-1.15.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and
> latest version

In the /usr/lib64/php/modules/ I don't see **php_mbstring.dll**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dlls (Dynamic Loadable Library) is being used only in Windows. For Linux (and BSD and probably most of unix-like OS'es) you have `.so` (shared object) instead. You probably need to change `.dll` to `.so` in php.ini or one of files included in it (it may be something like `/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini` or something similar).

Also, you can find path of .so file by running `rpm -ql php-mbstring` - it will list all files belonging to package.